# Setting directories to null values for a batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, directory, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble getting this batch script to run the way I want it to. Instead of entering each parameter manually, I want it so I can just hit the enter key in CMD and it will automatically populate with the corresponding IF's in the latter portion of the code.

```
::Setting of Variables
@Set /P RScript=Set path to R:_
@Set /P RProgram=Set path to RScript:_   
@Set /P RStartDir=Set Start Directory:_   
@Set /P BeginSims=Begin on which Loan?:_       
@Set /P EndSims=End on which Loan?:_         
@Set /P OutputDir=Set Output Directory:_   
@Set /P Deal=Set Deal input file (.txt):_         
@Set /P OutputFile=Name Deal Output File:_  
@Set /P AsOfDate=As of Date?:_  
@Set /P ThirtyYrSpread=Thirty Year Mortgage Spread?:_

::Inputs for Variables
::  "c:\program files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe"      RScript
::  "c:\cirt 2014 - 1\model.r"                            RProgram
::  "c:\cirt 2014 - 1"                                    RStartDir
::  1                                                     BeginSims
::  5                                                     EndSims
::  "C:\BatchAll"                                         OutputDir
::  "2014-1 Loan.txt"                                     Deal
::  "2014-1"                                              OutputFile
::  "62017"                                               AsOfDate
::  "135"                                                 ThirtyYrSpread
::Command Prompt, /c Carries out command specified by string and then terminates, processing the R script and outputting a CSV file.
cmd /c ""%RScript%" "%RProgram%" "%RStartDir%" "%Begin%" "%End%" "%OutputDir%" "%Deal%" "%OutputFile%" "%AsOfDate%" "%ThirtyYrSpread%""

::if [%RScript%]==[] Set RScript=c:\program files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe
::if [%RProgram%]==[] Set RProgram=C:\Cirt 2014 - 1\0.Mortgage Model.R
::if [%RStartDir%]==[] Set RStartDir=C:\Cirt 2014 - 1
::if [%Begin%]==[] Set Begin=1
::if [%End%]==[] Set End=5
::if [%OutputDir%]==[] Set OutputDir=C:\Cirt 2014 - 1
::if [%Deal%]==[] Set Deal=2014-1 Loan.txt
::if [%OutputFile%]==[] Set OutputFile=2014-1
::if [%AsOfDate%]==[] Set AsOfDate=62017
::if [%ThirtyYrSpread%] == [] Set ThirtyYrSpread=135`
```

Currently it's throwing an error on the first variable, RScript. It details,

```
files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe]==[] was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\msamuels\Desktop>if [c:\program files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe]==[] Set RScript=c:\program files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe
```

I've been fooling around with it for a while, was wondering if anyone had any suggestions? All necessary files are in the directory, as when I run it without the IF's and enter the variables manually, things work fine.

Comment: You have to "double quote" variables containing spaces like the path in your error not [brackets]

Comment: So like, if ""RScript""==[] instead of [%RScript%]==[]?

Comment: NO, like this `if "%RScript%"=="" Set "RScript=c:\program files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe"`

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. Trying it out now!

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually I don't believe the code you posted works as you have most of the lines commented out by `::`...

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set all the variables before asking for input.  If you hit enter at an input prompt the variable remains unchanged.

```
@echo off
:: defaults
Set "RScript=c:\program files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe"
Set "RProgram=C:\Mortgage\Cirt 2014 - 1\0.Mortgage Model.R"
Set "RStartDir=C:\Mortgage\Cirt 2014 - 1"
Set "Begin=1"
Set "End=5"
Set "OutputDir=C:\Mortgage\Cirt 2014 - 1"
Set "Deal=Cirt 2014-1 Loan Level.txt"
Set "OutputFile=Cirt 2014-1d"
Set "AsOfDate=62017"
Set "ThirtyYrSpread=135"

::Setting of Variables
ECHO PRESS ENTER AT ANY INPUT TO ACCEPT the DEFAULT VALUE.
Set /P "RScript=Set path to R:_"
Set /P "RProgram=Set path to RScript:_"
Set /P "RStartDir=Set Start Directory:_"
Set /P "BeginSims=Begin on which Loan?:_"
Set /P "EndSims=End on which Loan?:_"
Set /P "OutputDir=Set Output Directory:_"
Set /P "Deal=Set Deal input file (.txt):_"
Set /P "OutputFile=Name Deal Output File:_"
Set /P "AsOfDate=As of Date?:_"
Set /P "ThirtyYrSpread=Thirty Year Mortgage Spread?:_"


:: Command Prompt, /c Carries out command specified by string and then terminates, processing the R script and outputting a CSV file.
echo cmd /c "%RScript%" "%RProgram%" "%RStartDir%" "%Begin%" "%End%" "%OutputDir%" "%Deal%" "%OutputFile%" "%AsOfDate%" "%ThirtyYrSpread%"
pause
```

And here is the output from just hitting enter at every user prompt.

```
PRESS ENTER AT ANY INPUT TO ACCEPT the DEFAULT VALUE.
Set path to R:_
Set path to RScript:_
Set Start Directory:_
Begin on which Loan?:_
End on which Loan?:_
Set Output Directory:_
Set Deal input file (.txt):_
Name Deal Output File:_
As of Date?:_
Thirty Year Mortgage Spread?:_
cmd /c "c:\program files\r\r-3.4.3\bin\x64\rscript.exe" "C:\Mortgage\Cirt 2014 - 1\0.Mortgage Model.R" "C:\Mortgage\Cirt 2014 - 1" "1" "5" "C:\Mortgage\Cirt 2014 - 1" "Cirt 2014-1 Loan Level.txt" "Cirt 2014-1d" "62017" "135"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't have R installed so I am just echoing the command at the end. Remove the `ECHO` before `CMD` to execute your R script.

Comment: Another great way of looking at it, thanks for your response. I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: It works! Just needed to add more " " around the whole statement after cmd /c " ""...... "

Comment: @matrixfox, Rscript must be weird with that.  Normally the only time you need to do that is if your concatenating commands for `CMD.exe` to run. You are just running one command with command line arguments.

Comment: @matrixfox, in reality you should not even need to use `CMD /C` to run `Rscript.exe`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll play around with it a little more to make it more 'bare bones'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Squashman, seeing your comment on my other thread lets continue here. When i posed this question I neglected to take into account the fact that I have my variables coded in my R script as well.

Comment: At this point I think it becomes an R related question on, how to remove the hardcoded variables, and writing the loop that will take care of accepting the input parameters given through the batch itself (that you've done a nice job of writing).